# How to determine why mongodb stops with "signal":15,

Tags: mongodb

I'm running mongodb 6.08 on an AWS linux t2.2xlarge instance. A parallel process is communicating with the database with 8 processes running in parallel.

Now and then a signal 15 error stops the mongodb process midway through the process. I'd like to understand how to determine why the database is getting this signal. What logs should I look into for example.

{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-20T21:47:54.471+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":15,"error":"Terminated"}}

Other than that I don't see any problems in the log.

Is it possible to overload the mongodb in such a way that it would just stop working?

Are their settings I should adjust to help prevent the problem or to restart mongodb immediately?

**/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
Environment="MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK=1"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
RuntimeDirectory=mongodb
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
fs.file-max=98000

kernel.pid_max=64000

kernel.threads-max=64000

vm.max_map_count=128000
```

**Syslog**

```
Jul 29 00:52:31 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal dhclient[3510]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 123970ms.
Jul 29 00:54:35 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal dhclient[3510]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 109590ms.
Jul 29 00:56:25 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal dhclient[3510]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 111090ms.
Jul 29 00:58:16 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal dhclient[3510]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 120190ms.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Cloud-init target.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Execute cloud user/final scripts.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice system-selinux\x2dpolicy\x2dmigrate\x2dlocal\x2
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target rpc_pipefs.target.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Job spooling tools...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal chronyd[3253]: chronyd exiting
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Dynamically Generate Message Of The Day.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping NTP client/server...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping amazon-ssm-agent...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI Event Daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal amazon-ssm-agent[3710]: 2023-07-29 00:58:29 INFO [amazon-ssm-agent] amazo
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal amazon-ssm-agent[3710]: 2023-07-29 00:58:29 INFO [amazon-ssm-agent] Stopp
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal amazon-ssm-agent[3710]: 2023-07-29 00:58:29 INFO [amazon-ssm-agent] [Long
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping MongoDB Database Server...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping D-Bus System Message Bus...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Cloud-config availability.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice system-ec2net\x2difup.slice.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unmounting RPC Pipe File System...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Serial Getty on ttyS0...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Command Scheduler...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Closed LVM2 poll daemon socket.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Resets System Activity Logs.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping OpenSSH server daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal sshd[3774]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped irqbalance daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Job spooling tools.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped OpenSSH server daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped OpenSSH Server Key Generation.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Wake threshold service.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal rsyslogd[3703]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-57.amzn2.2
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped NTP client/server.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unmounted RPC Pipe File System.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal crond[3720]: (CRON) INFO (Shutting down)
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Command Scheduler.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Serial Getty on ttyS0.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal postfix/postfix-script[9259]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal postfix/master[3689]: terminating on signal 15
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Power Off Screen...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice system-getty.slice.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Permit User Sessions...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Permit User Sessions.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target NFS client services.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping GSSAPI Proxy Daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped GSSAPI Proxy Daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 9274 (plymouthd).
Jul 29 00:58:29 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Power Off Screen.
Jul 29 00:58:30 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal acpid[3882]: exiting
Jul 29 00:58:30 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped ACPI Event Daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:31 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 29 00:58:36 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal amazon-ssm-agent[3710]: 2023-07-29 00:58:36 INFO [amazon-ssm-agent] Bye.
Jul 29 00:58:36 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped amazon-ssm-agent.
Jul 29 00:58:36 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Network is Online.
Jul 29 00:58:36 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Network.
Jul 29 00:58:36 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal ec2net[9362]: [remove_aliases] Removing aliases of eth0
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal network[9293]: Shutting down interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal network[9293]: Shutting down loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Network (Pre).
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Slices.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice User and Session Slice.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Closed RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Flexible branding.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target System Initialization.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Read and set NIS domainname from /etc/sysconfig/netwo
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Random Seed...
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Setup Virtual Console.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Random Seed.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Security Auditing Service...
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal auditd[3188]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Security Auditing Service.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1305 audit(1690592317.305:174): audit_pid=0 old=3188 
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.309:175): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.325:176): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Configure read-only root support.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dme
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.345:177): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.361:178): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.381:179): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmev
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping LVM2 metadata daemon...
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.477:180): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1690592317.493:181): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting Power-Off...
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Closed LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Jul 29 00:58:37 ip-172-31-14-19.ca-central-1.compute.internal systemd-journal[2090]: Journal stopped
```

Regards
Conteh

Comment: Signal 15 is SIGTERM, a usual method to gracefully stop a program. You need to figure out who/what is stopping it.

Comment: It seems to stop randomly as far as I know. Sometimes the processing finishes correctly and sometimes it doesn't. I don't know what could be causing the termination. I suspect the parallel process overloads the database. I don't see anything in log though to suggest a problem.

Comment: It may appear random to you, but someone or something does send this signal. Have you looked at syslog and the auditd log?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've updated the question to be specific about how to determine what is causing the mongodb to stop. I don't see the syslog in /var/log on aws linux. I've restarted sudo service rsyslog restart. I looked at the audit log but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's interesting my process uses the mongo database effectively for an hour and then for 2hrs it uses a different database system. It then returns to use the MongoDb and the system sometimes can no longer connect to the mongodb database. Does mongodb become inactive after a period of time?

Comment: The system logs are located at /var/log/messages. Adding the log into the question